# Installed 12.10, won't boot

Tags: installation, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I was running 12.04 without any problem on a Dell Inspiron 6000.  I upgraded to 12.10, but now it won't boot.  I can get to Bios and to the boot menu, but 12.10 simply won't boot.  I can run it from the DVD, but not from the install on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a Dell d510.  I had 12.04 32 bit run fine, but it doesn't boot after the upgrade I performed yesterday.

I still managed to boot it with the old kernel left over from 12.04 by pressing the shift key after BIOS, then you can get to the Grub menu and choose the 12.04 kernel.

I don't have a solution to boot with the 12.10 kernel, I need to attach a serial console because the display is blank.